# How can I work with my model without a database in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, view, model, controller

I want to put my variables with static data (hardcoded) in the model -without database-

and use it with my controller and manipulate the view.

how I can do this in ruby on rails?

Answer (score 1):

You could put a class in `app/models/` that doesn't inherit from `ActiveRecord`

```
# find me in app/models/my_class.rb
class MyClass
    attr_accessor :prop1, :prop2, :prop3
end
```

Use it in a controller like this:

```
# find me in app/controllers/some_controller.rb
class SomeController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @my_class = MyClass.new
        @my_class.prop1 = "Hello"
        @my_class.prop2 = "World"
        @my_class.prop3 = 1
        # etc.
    end
end
```